# How to set propertys of decoding h264 in Emgu cv?

Tags: c#, h.264, emgucv, rtsp

I use Emgu CV from capuring RTSP stream in h264 from camera.

I get stream, but i need to set "fps" and "yadif" flags. How i can do it?

If i'm not setting "yadif" i see some artifacts on image:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GumkU.png)

When i use ffplay.exe for test i have no artifacts:

```
ffplay.exe -flags low_delay  -rtsp_transport tcp  -i rtsp://192.168.1.232/rtsp_tunnel?line=3  -vf "yadif=0:0,fps=30"
```

Comment: They have a really good documentation side, there you should be able to find everything you need. I'd start [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/766b735b-77fa-f092-3d40-21545a7d0d8f.htm)

Comment: I read this. but I couldn't find an analogue of the "yadif" property in this documentation.

Comment: yadif = `yet another deinterlace filter`, as far I was able to spot, there is no deinterlacing on emgucv side. I can't suggest you any project as of right now which implements yadif for c# but I'm sure there is something. You'd need to use that too in order to deinterlace your video. But I guess any deinterlacing filter will work too, not just yadif.

Comment: As i understand i need  to do:
1)use emguCV for getting frame
2)then using  something else for deinterlacing it.
  is it correct?

Comment: Yes but I've to be honest that I'm no expert for emgucv, but that's how I would try to do it. Mybe someone experienced with emgucv can say more to it.

Comment: Oh, now i understed where is problem! Thank a lot!!